# want to confirm popup with "Yes" and "No" button when user click on add to cart

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am new in Wordpress so need help...
I want to show confirm popup with the button "Yes" and "No" when user clicks on Add to Cart. after selecting "Yes" on confirm Popup, add a product to cart. If user select "No" the close confirm popup and do nothing.
Also, I want to show product data filed value on confirm popup body section.

Update:
i already try with hook(woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation) and some javascript but not able to get it.

Thanks in Advanced...

Comment: can you edit the question and add what all you tried?

Comment: @Akshat  i try hook(woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation) and some javascript but not able to get it.